# You want it, yet you don't really

Tags: riddle

> You may want it ***here***.
>
> But if you have it **real**,
>
> it will bite.
>
> You'd want it out.
>
> Carefully, do it right.
>
> But be quick,
>
> You don't want a lime.

What is that?

PS. I changed the wording of the riddle, hopefully it is less ambiguous now.

Comment: @ A E - not really. Perhaps I might add some more information, but don't want to give away too much.

Comment: @AE if there are so many valid answers, why there isn't even one that fits all the clues entirely?

Comment: Is the English awful for a puzzle related purpose, or is it just because it's not your native tongue?

Comment: @JonathanAllan man that was cruel...

Comment: @KeithN it's not meant to be!

Comment: @JonathanAllan, it is not my native tongue, I tried to make it sound like a poem, so I might not have done a good job. Is there a particular phrase that bothers you?

Comment: Mostly the "you may want it here", and "get it real" as they do not quite make sense; but almost every line seems quirky in some way...

Comment: OK - I made some edits - please check them to see if the puzzle still makes sense!

Comment: Well, no, here is an important clue, it was even bolded. So I will revert them

Comment: @JonathanAllan, and "get it for real" is also possible, but it is not necessary in the intended meaning. "in real life" might be more appropriate, but still not really needed. As you can "get it" and you will not like it. :)

Comment: Qn discussed at http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5259/4050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the answer is

> [tick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick)

Because

> You may want them here (the answer accepted ticks on SE), but you don't want them (the tiny arachnids) in your home.

Comment: Just to be thorough, the last line is referring to [Lyme Disease](https://www.cdc.gov/lyme/)

Comment: @DasBeasto weird, it was added since.

Answer (score 1):

might be

> fame

> i dont need to explain it.

Comment: You may want that in real. It doesn't really fit, unless I am missing something from your answer.

Comment: In india there's actor name called [shahrukh khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Rukh_Khan/).....first time i saw him on a airport....when i was approaching towards him...peoples already gathered around him..n block his way to reach their car...i think he took 2 hours to walk 200m distance.....so  fame can cost you

Comment: Still, the thing I am referring to - you wouldn't want it in the first place. A lot of people want fame. No one wants this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> Pokemons

You may think they are cute and adorable but

> They are creatures that may easily kill you

Comment: Someone could still want them regardless. :)